# How to compare float value in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

```
 SELECT `UM`.`usermaster_id`, `UM`.`height`, `UM`.`income_range`, 
`UM`.`surname`, `UM`.`display_name`, `UM`.`about_me`, `UM`.`profile_id`, 
`UM`.`marital_status`, `UM`.`birth_date`, `UM`.`age`, `UM`.`gender`, 
`UM`.`mother_tongue_id`, `UM`.`religion_id`, `UM`.`cast_id`, 
`UM`.`sub_cast_id`, `UM`.`highest_degree`, `UM`.`occupation`, `UM`.`city_id`,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, `birth_date`, CURDATE()) as newage FROM (`user_master` 
UM) WHERE ( UM.height >= 5.7 AND UM.height <= 5.11 AND UM.income_range 
IN(4,7,5,8,9,10) AND UM.cast_id IN(3,15,7) AND UM.marital_status IN('Never 
Married') ) AND `UM`.`gender` = 'Male' AND `UM`.`active` = 1 HAVING `newage`
BETWEEN 31 AND 34
```

height column value display record not found.

Comment: Use DECIMAL instead. Don't use HAVING in this context. Just use WHERE, and repeat the formula for calculating newage.

Answer (score 0):

can you just remove the UM since you are only referencing to just one table only?

Comment: height >= 5.7 AND height <= 5.11 - How to compare in mysql i have use data type is varchar. um is alise name of table

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you have missed a closing parenthesis :

```
<?php
//connect to the database
$conn = myslqi_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_test") or trigger_error(mysqli_error($conn));
//prepare the statement
$sql = "SELECT UM.usermaster_id, UM.height, UM.income_range, UM.surname, M.display_name,UM.about_me,UM.profile_id,UM.marital_status,UM.birth_date, UM.age, UM.gender, UM.mother_tongue_id, UM.religion_id, UM.cast_id, UM.sub_cast_id, UM.highest_degree, UM.occupation, UM.city_id, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birth_date, CURDATE()) as newage 
    FROM (user_master UM) 
    WHERE ( UM.height >= 5.7 AND UM.height <= 5.11) 
    AND UM.income_range IN(4,7,5,8,9,10) 
    AND UM.cast_id IN(3,15,7) 
    AND UM.marital_status ='Never Married'
    AND UM.gender = 'Male' 
    AND UM.active = 1 
    HAVING newage BETWEEN 31 AND 34";
//execute the sql
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or or trigger_error(mysqli_error($conn));
//declare a blank array
$data = array();
//verify if there are records
if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){
//there are records
//loop through the records and store it in the array
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
array_push($data, $row);//push the contents
}//loop ends
}//if ends

//at this point either the array has data or do not have any records
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Rest you can do anything what you like to do with the records. As per your question, *comparing floating values* now do you need these records to be sorted on the basis of height?